Formula Conversion to ARRAYFORMULA
I have this formula in Google Sheets that helps me get the order of occurrence of an email when the email is a duplicate: =IF(COUNTIF($B$3:B3,B3)=1,1,COUNTIF($B$3:B3,B3))
I'm trying to get the same formula but in the ARRAYFORMULA. Usually, I would use MAP/LAMBDA to solve the issue, but in this case the arrays are of different size so it does not work.
This is my spreadsheet to help better understand.

Looks like simple =COUNTIF($B$3:B3,B3) gives the same results as your current formula.

Yes you are right, I was trying to cover a case that didn't need to be covered ...


You may try:
=map(B3:index(B:B,match(,0/(B:B<>""))),lambda(Σ,countif(B3:Σ,Σ)))



Thank you works perfectly! Index/Match was the key to the solution
